# __m256i version of _mm_test_all_zeros

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I know how to test if an _m128i register is all zero with the `_mm_test_all_zeros` intrinsic.

What is the AVX2 / __m256i version of this intrinsic? If one isn't available, what is the fastest way to test if all 256 bits in a SIMD register are zero?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fastest is probably `vptest` instruction.

```c
// Return 1 if `x` is all zeros, otherwise 0
inline int test_all_zeros( __m256i x )
{
    return _mm256_testz_si256( x, x );
}
```